# Base Image Missing When Uploading Images With Wordpress

Tags: iis, images

Whenever i upload an image (ball.png) wordpress will auto generate a bunch of smaller images that are different sizes. e.g. ball-300x200.png. These images display fine, but when i set on of these images a featured image it shows up as a broken image. When i set a featured image for a post it uses the base image "uploads/2015/07/ball.png", but this image does not exist. All of the other size variations of this image exist, but not the main image. This happens for every image that i try to upload.

All of the thumbnails generated when i upload an image are valid images that are smaller versions of the main image. Im not sure why the main image is going missing.

Im running wordpress under IIS 8.

Comment: What code are you using to display the image? Can you add the code to the question?

Comment: Im not using any code to display it. The file doesnt seem to exist on the disk. When i type the url of the file into the browser i get an error 500.

Comment: Can you try disabling all plugins and using one of the default themes and then check if this is still happening?